# VBA- Not recognizing new values in columns when searching for duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I am running VBA to search for differences in values in rows between column D and column G. My code works for the first try, but  when I add more values towards the end (that are not the same values), the code doesn't seem to follow.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RateTest1()
Const COLUMN_1 = "D", WS1_START = 2
Const COLUMN_2 = "G", WS2_START = 2
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, col1 As Variant, col2 As Variant,     tr As Long
Dim max1 As Long, max2 As Long, r1 As Long, r2 As Long, red As Long, found As Boolean
Dim miss As Range

tr = Rows.Count:                         red = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"): max1 = ws1.Cells(tr, COLUMN_1).End(xlUp).Row
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"): max2 = ws2.Cells(tr, COLUMN_2).End(xlUp).Row

col1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, COLUMN_1), ws1.Cells(max1, COLUMN_1))
col2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, COLUMN_2), ws2.Cells(max2, COLUMN_2))

For r2 = WS2_START To max2
    For r1 = WS1_START To max1
        If Len(col1(r1, 1)) > 0 And col1(r1, 1) <> "N/A" Then
            found = (col1(r1, 1) = col2(r2, 1))
            If found Then Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not found Then
        If miss Is Nothing Then
            Set miss = ws2.Cells(r2, COLUMN_2)
        Else
            Set miss = Union(miss, ws2.Cells(r2, COLUMN_2))
        End If
    End If
Next
miss.Interior.Color = red


For r2 = WS2_START To max2
    For r1 = WS1_START To max1
        If Len(col2(r2, 1)) > 0 And col1(r2, 1) <> "N/A" Then
            found = (col1(r2, 1) = col2(r1, 1))
            If found Then Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not found Then
        If miss Is Nothing Then
            Set miss = ws2.Cells(r2, COLUMN_2)
        Else
            Set miss = Union(miss, ws2.Cells(r2, COLUMN_2))
        End If
    End If
Next
miss.Interior.Color = red

End Sub
```

The codes sometimes only recognizes that column D and G are different if the value in D is greater than G and hardly ever the other way around. The "N/A" code is there because eventually I want to add code that *does not* highlight if column D has a 1 and column G has an "N/A". Those are considered the same values.

Comment: are you aware that ws1 and ws2 refer to the same worksheet   ... you can get rid of ws2 and use ws1 .... _ws1_ is just a "shorthand of sorts" for _ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")_

Comment: yes, before I had these sets on two separate sheets, but now I find it easier to have them both on the same sheet. I just didn't change the code for that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 procedures will find differences (non-empty values) between the two columns, with the exception of value "1" in column D, and value "N/A" in column G

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RateTest()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, miss As Range, tmp As Range, t As Double
    Dim max1 As Long, max2 As Long, colD As Range, colG As Range

    t = Timer
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    max1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    max2 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    Set colD = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "D"), ws.Cells(max1, "D"))
    Set colG = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "G"), ws.Cells(max2, "G"))
    colD.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    colG.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone

    Set miss = CheckColumns(colD, colG, "N/A")

    If miss Is Nothing Then
        Set miss = CheckColumns(colG, colD, "1")
    Else
        Set tmp = CheckColumns(colG, colD, "1")
        If Not tmp Is Nothing Then Set miss = Union(miss, tmp)
    End If

    If Not miss Is Nothing Then miss.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print "Rows: " & max1 & "; Time: " & Format(Timer - t, "0.000") & " sec"
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function CheckColumns(col1 As Range, col2 As Range, x As String) As Range

    Dim c As Variant, r As Long, d As Object, rng As Range

    col1.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00###"
    c = col1.Value2
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
    For r = 1 To UBound(c)
        With col1.Cells(r)
            If .Errors.Item(xlNumberAsText).Value Then .Value2 = .Value2 + 0
        End With
        d(Trim$(CStr(c(r, 1)))) = vbNullString
    Next

    c = col2.Value2
    For r = 1 To UBound(c)
        If Len(c(r, 1)) > 0 Then
            If c(r, 1) <> x Then
                If Not d.exists(Trim(CStr(c(r, 1)))) Then
                    If rng Is Nothing Then
                        Set rng = col2.Cells(r)
                    Else
                        Set rng = Union(rng, col2.Cells(r))
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set CheckColumns = rng
End Function
```

---

**Edit** to include test results:

[image: TestData][image]

---

Number Format:

[image: NumberFormatWindow]

MS reference to [Cells().Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.errors.item.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: This works great again! Any thoughts on why a "0" in column G would highlight with a "0" is column "D"? Would it recognize they are the same value and not highlight? And if it does chose to highlight? Should it highlight in column D? This is the only instance, everything else works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: @Ben, I just noticed the code will not highlight values "1" and "N/A" in **both** columns. I'll make some changes that will not highlight "1" in column D, and not show "N/A" in col G; I'll include testing for "0" as well - I'll update it shortly

Comment: Paul, everything seems to work very well. I was doing some testing on it and see that if I replace a 1 with a 0.5 in column D while there is a 1 in column G, and run the code again, it does not highlight D red. I got very lost in your last edit so I was not gonna try to fiddle with it myself. Do you have an edit for this? Thank you so much for all your help so far.

Comment: I tested the same scenario you mentioned and it works as expected (see the image in the answer). The last edit was to use a Dictionary object to make it faster - the first edit was too slow

Comment: Yeah I am unsure. I tried different rows. I tried 0.6 in D with 1 in G and 1.5 in D with 1 in G and it worked but the 0.5 in D with 1 in G still did not highlight. At the end of the day, it's not the end of the world. The likely hood of that occurrence when I am using this in my other testing is most likely slim to none.

Comment: If you will be comparing decimals you can be more precise: 1.777 will be different than 1.778, so on the range (col D) change it to 2 decimal places: `colD.NumberFormat = "0.00"`, or in code use `Format(val, "0.00")`, or `Round(val, 2)`, and this fill force the storage of "0.50" (as a string) instead of 0.5. Let me know if you want me to make a change for this.

Comment: I am not sure that is the issue. I have other values that are rounded and work. I have been trying different combinations of numbers greater and less than 1 in column D with a 1 in the G column. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: If you can provide a small set of values for columns D and G, like in the image, so I can duplicate the issue we should be able to get it working

Comment: Added the new screenshot. I do not know if it matters but I have vlookups and index functions in the G column. As you can see, the first set works but the 2nd row does not for some reason.

Comment: I made a small change to CheckColumns() - added `.Value2` when extracting the array from the range to make sure it uses only the values and not the formulas; maybe this will fix the issue

Comment: Still getting the same issue. I added another screen shot. It seems like the number 0.5 is causing issues a lot of the time (Row 2 and 5). I don't know if you want to try to recreate and see if 0.5 and those other combinations have the same result.

Comment: I duplicated your test data and am getting different results. I noticed that your Number Format is inconsistent and this is important; make sure you set the **Number Format** same as in the Format Cells image, for both columns D and G; select "Number" and 2 decimal places. Your D column is left-aligned which usually indicates that the values are treated as text, as opposed to Column G which is right-aligned, and treated as Numbers. Text vs Numbers shouldn't make a difference as long as you have the consistent number of digits displayed - all "1"s should be "1.00", and "0.6" should be "0.60"

Comment: I did the same steps as you and on a blank workbook as well and still receiving an error with 0.5 in column D. I am really stumped. Thank you for your help, Paul.

Comment: That's strange; try using `Trim$()` on the values added to the dictionary `Trim$(d(CStr(c(r, 1)))) = vbNullString`, and again when calling `d.Exists()`: `If Not d.Exists(Trim$(CStr(c(r, 1)))) Then`. It would be good to know what's causing this. Also, if you can, step through the code by using F8, repeatedly, to see the actual values added to the dictionary

Comment: Added the code and received the error "Function call on left-hard side of assignment must return Variant or Object." I tried changing some of the variable data types but couldn't figure out the issue. When pressing F8 it gets to line 39 and 40 and just goes back and forth.

Comment: I made a few more changes to function CheckColumns() - Trim$(), NumberFormat, and Cells().Errors.Item(xlNumberAsText).Value (it might help)